# Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision

Tags: c#, azure, artificial-intelligence, azure-cognitive-services

Via the web front end I was able to upload a png file of an invoice and ask the question "What was sold". It came back with the product sold and the price from the invoice perfectly. It did this twice with perfect results.

I am now struggling to understand how to reproduce this in c# code.

I have tried the following and it doesn't recognise any objects with the exact image i used via the web.

This is the code I have managed to get together so far...

```
// Create a ComputerVisionClient object with your subscription key and endpoint
string subscriptionKey = "redactedd";
string endpoint = "redacted";
var client = new ComputerVisionClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(subscriptionKey))
{
Endpoint = endpoint
};

// Analyze an uploaded image and print the product name and price
string imagePath = "C:\\Users\\Trevo\\Pictures\\Yacht\\img_20220709_125430.jpg";

var features = new List<VisualFeatureTypes?>()
{
    //VisualFeatureTypes.Categories,
    //VisualFeatureTypes.Description,
    //VisualFeatureTypes.Faces,
    //VisualFeatureTypes.ImageType,
    //VisualFeatureTypes.Tags,
    //VisualFeatureTypes.Adult,
    //VisualFeatureTypes.Color,
    //VisualFeatureTypes.Brands,
    VisualFeatureTypes.Objects
};

using Stream imageStream = File.OpenRead(imagePath);

// Call the Computer Vision API to analyse the image
var result = await client.AnalyzeImageInStreamAsync(imageStream, features);

// Find the object with the highest confidence score
DetectedObject? bestObject = null;
double bestScore = 0;
foreach (var obj in result.Objects)
{
    if (obj.Confidence > bestScore)
    {
        bestObject = obj;
        bestScore = obj.Confidence;
    }
}
// Print the object name and price if found
if (bestObject != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"The product name is: {bestObject.ObjectProperty}");
    Console.WriteLine($"The product price is: {bestObject.Parent.ObjectProperty}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No product found in the image.");
}
```

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to upload and image of an invoice and ask the question "What as sold?" please?

Comment: Which screen are you referring "webfront"?

Comment: @Venkatesan copilot.microsoft.com

Comment: This is a console application code, Create a windows application and re-use the same code. Create a file control for uploading an invoice and a button click function to call the cognitive service and return the source/result to the screen.

Comment: Can you add the pics of how you getting on output? because image analysis will not give any text from the image.